# Upgrade Sony Xperia M Dual C2005 to Lollipop CM12

Tags: cyanogenmod, updates, 5.1-lollipop, sony-xperia-m-dual

want to upgrade my Android OS from Jellybean 4.3 to Lollipop but unfortunately Sony has ended it's support for my phone, Sony Xperia M Dual-SIM C2005. I've searched in google about Sony Xperia M upgrade to Lollipop but the result always for single-SIM. My question is can I still upgrade my phone (Sony Xperia M Dual C2005)? If I can, how? Do I have to format all internal memory and can't be backed up?

Thanks